# Haskell extract element with the key

Tags: haskell

Hi i have a little bit issue with Haskell, i'm new to the language so here is the problem , i have :

```
data Setup v = Setup {
    SetupMap   :: Map.Map v Status,
    SetupGraph :: Graph v
}
```

and i want to implement this function :

```
st :: Ord v => Setup v -> v -> Status
```

it should return the status of the key map ,i tried a couple things but didn't compile such as :

```
st c e = Map.fromList(Map.keys . SetupMap c ) Map.! e
```

i'm stuck and lack of ideas . thanks

Comment: Your data definition is, as far as I know, not valid Haskell: types should start with uppercase, and properties/functions with lowercase. Can you please first rewrite the question, as well as explain (in natural language) what you im to solve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah ofc , first i changed the data like you said , and my question is what is the correct syntax for me to implement a function with this : st :: Ord v => Setup v -> v -> Status

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
data Setup v = Setup {
    setupMap   :: Map.Map v Status,
    setupGraph :: Graph v
}

st :: Ord v => Setup v -> v -> Status
st c e = setupMap c Map.! e
```

Note that `Map.!` will crash your program when the key is not present. You should return `Maybe Status` instead and use `Map.!?` which is safe.

Comment: Thanks i like the idea with the `Maybe` it helped me a lot , by the way what do you suggest for  a function `isHere :: Ord v => Setup v -> v -> Bool` i tought about using `Map.member` but i always fail with the syntax, the function should check if the element at key has the correct status

Comment: @Haskell-newb try `Map.member e (setupMap c)`